# In the function $f(x)=k\ln(ax+b)$ what does the $k$ value represent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

Basically what the title of the question is, in the function $f(x)=k\ln(ax+b)$ I presume that $a$ is the slope, $k\ln(b)$ is the y intercept but what is $k$?

Comment: This function has no universal slope, since the slope (of the tangent) changes at each point.  Also, the $y$-intercept is $k\ln b$, not $b$.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense sorry, I did end up calculating it as 1 using that formula that you mentioned, will edit it in a second to be more clear. But in any general log function in the form $f(x)=k∗ln(ax+b)$, what does K stand for then??

Comment: $a$ is not the slope, and $b$ is not the $y$-intercept.

Comment: $k$ is an overall scale.

Answer (score 0):

$k, a$ and $b$ are just constants, which you might choose. For example you could set $k=1$, $a=2$ and $b=10$. The question is to find the values of these parameters, so you get the pictured graph.

You can see for example that the point (0|0) lies on the graph.

Hence you have $f(0)=0$, which translates to $k\ln(a\cdot 0+b)=0$.

So $k\ln(b)=0$. Can you deduce the value of $b$?

Do you find more information in the pictured graph to deduce the other values?

You might want to check a function plotter, like geogebra:

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator

Plug in the expression k * ln(a * x +b)

There you will be able to change the values for $k$, $a$ and $b$, and you will see how this affects the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $y-k=f(x-h)$ simply translates the graph of $y=f(x)$ so that $(h,k)$ is the new origin (e.g. if $h,k>0$, this would mean translating $y=f(x)$ to the right by $h$ units and up by $k$ units).

The graph of $y=Af(x)$ vertically stretches the graph of $y=f(x)$ by a factor of $A$ (note that if $A<0$, the graph is reflected over the $x$-axis and stretched by a factor of $|A|$).

Your example has both of these transformations for $a\neq 0$ applied to $y=\ln x$:

$$y=k\ln (ax+b)\implies y-k\ln(a)=k\ln (x-(-b/a)).$$

As for finding what $k,a,b$ are in your example, you can do so if you know three points on your function, from which you can set up three equations and solve for these parameters.